# How to convert a column of objects having True and False to 1s and 0s ? The column is not Boolean in nature and is object in nature

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I have a dataset in which the target variable is False and True but the column is not Boolean in nature rather an object. I have tried these but they don't work:-

```
df_new['Y_var'] = df_new['Y_var'].map({'True': 1, 'False': 0})
```

and

```
df_new['Y_var']=df_new[Y_var'].replace(['False','True'],[0,1])
```

and

```
df_new['Y_var'].astype(bool).astype(int)
```

output of `df_new['Y_var'].to_list()`:

```
[' False.', ' False.', ' False.', ' False.', ' True.', ' False.', ' False.', ' False.', ' False.', ' True.',.....]
```

Comment: You would have needed `map({True: 1, False: 0})` without quotes. If you can't solve it, please provide the output of `df_new['Y_var'].to_list()` (before any change)

Comment: @mozway no it isn't working it is giving me an NaN column , as i said the column is not boolean but an object type

Comment: please provide the requested output, object type can contain booleans…

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure they don't work?
The first one works for me.

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Y_var': "True"},
    {'Y_var': "False"},
    {'Y_var': "True"},
    {'Y_var': "False"},
    {'Y_var': "False"},
    {'Y_var': "True"},
])

df_new['Y_var'] = df_new['Y_var'].map({'True': 1, 'False': 0})
print(df_new)
```

Gives me:

```
   Y_var
0      1
1      0
2      1
3      0
4      0
5      1
```

Comment: No it is giving me an entire NaN column.

Answer (score -1):

this should work:

```
bool_list = [bool(x) for x in df_new["Y_var"]]
temp_df = pd.DataFrame({"Y_var": bool_list})
df_new.update(temp_df)
df_new["Y_var"] = df_new["Y_var"] * 1
```

[here is picture of it on my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK4gF.png)

Comment: No it is not working, Error:-IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Comment: @divinity27 try the second example you gave in your question but get rid off the '' around true and false

Comment: not working still , NaN error

Comment: @divinity27 i updated my answer, please try now

Comment: with your updated answer my column remains unchanged, the column is not boolean , but rather object in nature, did you read that?

Comment: @divinity27 i updated it again plz try it and lmk how it goes, it works in my test case

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever to use `eval` here…

Comment: @mozway yes there is, he has true and false as strings, you use eval to convert them to booleans, you may be able to use bool() instead of eval but still one of them is needed

Comment: No, I can assure you, this isn't a valid reason. In any case, OP should provide a clear reproducible example as DataFrame constructor, or dictionary/list.

Comment: @mozway yes he should provide that information but from the information i have what i did should be right and you cann see from the picture

Comment: It "works", it doesn't mean that it's right. You should probably never have to use `eval` in python code in your life. Anyway, let's wait for OP's clarification on the real data.

Comment: @mozway [' False.',
 ' False.',
 ' False.',
 ' False.',
 ' True.',
 ' False.',
 ' False.',
 ' False.',
 ' False.',
 ' True.',.....] 
This is my column to a list output

Comment: OK, so you have neither `True` nor `"True"`. You have `" True."`, the space and dot matter here. `df_new['Y_var'].map({' True.': 1, ' False.': 0})` should work. Or maybe `df_new['Y_var'].str.contains('true', case=False)` if you only expect True/False variations.

Comment: @Benjamin feel free to update your answer and to remove this ugly `eval`. (I'll then remove my downvote).

Comment: But still i am getting no change @mozway
my code:-
df_new['Y_var'].map({'True.': 1, 'False.': 0})
print(df_new['Y_var'])
 my output:-
0        False.
1        False.
2        False.
4        False.
5         True.
         ...   
3328     False.
3329     False.
3330     False.
3331      True.
3332     False.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the change of type, `df_new['Y_var'].str.contains('true', case=False).astype(int)`

Comment: @mozway better?

Comment: Yes it's working now , thanks @mozway, I guess it really helps to check out small formatting issues in data

Comment: @divinity27 next time, **please**, provide a reproducible input from the beginning, this saves everyone's time ;)

Comment: @BenjaminZatman no, for different reasons. Feel free to use my answer in yours.

Comment: @mozway, I will keep that in mind